# Webapi dynamic validations

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webapi

I am looking to validate a particular request depending on values in a database. It's a complex scenario, but I will try to simplify it in an example.

Say I have the following model:

```
public class EventDataForms
{
    public int Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_Type { get; set; }

    public string Field_data_Type { get; set; }

    public int Field_Min_Length { get; set; }
    public int Field_Max_Length { get; set; }


    public string Field_Name { get; set; }


    public string Field_Description { get; set; }
    public int Field_Order { get; set; }
    public Boolean Required_flag { get; set; }
    public int Event_Form_ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int Event_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
    public string Created_by { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }

}
```

When a POST request comes in, I need to make a call to get certain requirements for the Field_Name being passed

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = 'First Name';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'

>Field_Name = 'Last Name';


Field_data_Type = 'Email'
```

> Field_Name = 'Email';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = 'Gender';

```
Field_data_Type = 'numeric'
```

> Field_Name = 'Age';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = 'What"s  your T-shirt size';

```
Field_data_Type = 'numeric'
```

> Field_Name = 'PhoneNumber';

```
Field_data_Type = 'numeric'
```

> Field_Name = 'Zipcode';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = ' Street Address';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = 'Country';

```
Field_data_Type = 'String'
```

> Field_Name = 'State';

i want dynamic validations for these fields ..can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

MVC has a hook to provide your own ModelValidatorProvider. By default MVC 2 uses a sub class of ModelValidatorProvider called DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider that is able to use System.DataAnnotations.ComponentModel.ValidationAttribute attributes for validation.

The DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider uses reflection to find all the ValidationAttributes and simply loops through the collection to validate your models. All you need to do is override a method called GetValidators and inject your own attributes from whichever source you choose. I use this technique to do convention validations, the properties with DataType.Email attribute always gets passed through a regex, and use this technique to pull information from the database to apply more restrictive validations for "non-power" users.

The following example simply says "always make any FirstName properties required".

```
public class CustomMetadataValidationProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
 protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
    //go to db if you want
    //var repository = ((MyBaseController) context.Controller).RepositorySomething;

    //find user if you need it
    var user = context.HttpContext.User;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metadata.PropertyName) && metadata.PropertyName == "FirstName")
        attributes = new List<Attribute>() {new RequiredAttribute()};

    return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
 }
}
```

All you have to do is register the provider in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomMetadataValidationProvider());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```